# NSOpenPanel Hiding Xcode Debug

Tags: swift, xcode, nsopenpanel

I am working on an app that uses NSOpenPanel. The problem is that during debugging with Xcode the panel does not fully hide itself. A white rectangle is left being displayed over everything else. I have tried using a completion handler to resolve this issue as some have suggested it will, but so far I have had not luck with that.

Here is the code. I was expecting to see the entire widow for the panel disappear once the completion handler was entered, but no such luck. Here is the code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    func createPanel(){

    //setup NSOpenPanel
    let filePanel = NSOpenPanel();
    filePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["csv"]
    filePanel.title = "IMPORT CSV FILE"
    //Display Panel with completion handler
    filePanel.begin(completionHandler: ){ response in

    guard let url = filePanel.url else {
            return
        }

    let path = url.path
    // need the string value for url
    self.processFile(path:path)
        }
```

Thanks Jim

Comment: Call `orderOut`?

Comment: I called orderOut on the panel in the completion handler but it did not work. NSOpenPanel inherits from NSWindows so I believe that was correct??